# Add value from range to sum if checkbox is true

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I honestly don't even know where to begin with this one. It's my first time using checkboxes. I understand the general principle but the implementation is evading me.

What I'm trying to do is calculate a rough estimate of the scope of work for a fix/flip property in D14 by using a percentage of the ARV (Q5) and adding additional costs for "big ticket" items (T5:U16). Whether or not the "big ticket" items are included would depend on whether the linked cell for each checkbox (R7:P18) is TRUE. To further complicate matters, the cost for certain items need to be multiplied by data from other cells. Specifically, bathroom rehab (U7) needs to be multiplied by the number of bathrooms (D7), new plumbing (U9) needs to be multiplied by the number of stories (D8), new flooring (U14) and interior painting (U15) need to be multiplied by the square footage of the property (D5).

My gut instinct was sumif but that's not sufficient I don't think.

Any help would be appreciated. [Worksheet Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDsQJ.png)

P.S. I'm happy to share the acutal worksheet if someone can tell me how.

Comment: In excel True/False is equivalent to 1/0. So you just need to multiply that with the number you are calculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was using multiple IF functions within SUM.

Here's the final formula:

```
=SUM(IF(R7=TRUE,U5,0),IF(R8=TRUE,U6*D9,0),IF(R9=TRUE,U7*D9,0),IF(R10=TRUE,U8*D7,0),IF(R11=TRUE,U9*D9,0),IF(R12=TRUE,U10*D8*D9,0),IF(R13=TRUE,U11*D9,0),IF(R14=TRUE,U12*D9,0),IF(R15=TRUE,U13*D9,0),IF(R16=TRUE,U14*D9,0),IF(R17=TRUE,U15*D5,0),IF(R18=TRUE,U16*D5,0),IF(R19=TRUE,U17,0),IF(R20=TRUE,U18,0))
```